# Webrtc Media Tracks Events Mute/Unmute Not Aligning With Tracks On Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, webrtc, media

On mobile phones in which WebRTC is implemented inside a webview, when the user switches to another app on the phone, the webrtc video goes out, and when they come back to their app, the video comes back.

The tracks in WebRTC have this function for detecting when the video stops and comes back: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/mute_event

Here is where things get weird. The above functions work when the user goes to another app, except he keeps toggling between the mute and unmute action, like its try to reconnect. So I added a mute check as such:

```
if (track && track.type == 'video') {
    
                    track.addEventListener('mute', event => {

                        let muted = ((track && track.track && track.track.enabled != undefined && track.track.enabled == false) || (track && track.enabled != undefined && track.enabled == false)) ? true : false;

                        if (videoTracks[session_id] && muted == true) {
                            displayAvatar(session_id);
                        }

                    });

                    track.addEventListener('unmute', event => {

                        let muted = ((track && track.track && track.track.enabled != undefined && track.track.enabled == false) || (track && track.enabled != undefined && track.enabled == false)) ? true : false;

                        if (videoTracks[session_id] && muted == false) {
                            displayVideo(session_id);
                        }

                    });

                    if (track.track) {

                        track.track.addEventListener('mute', event => {

                            let muted = ((track && track.track && track.track.enabled != undefined && track.track.enabled == false) || (track && track.enabled != undefined && track.enabled == false)) ? true : false;

                            if (videoTracks[session_id] && muted == true) {
                                displayAvatar(session_id);
                            }


                        });

                        track.track.addEventListener('unmute', event => {


                            let muted = ((track && track.track && track.track.enabled != undefined && track.track.enabled == false) || (track && track.enabled != undefined && track.enabled == false)) ? true : false;

                            if (videoTracks[session_id] && muted == false) {
                                displayVideo(session_id);
                            }

                        });

                    }
```

The weird part is this, the track is always enabled and never muted. Meaning this:

```
track && track.track && track.track.enabled
```

or this

```
track && track.track && track.track.muted
```

Is always enabled and never muted, even when the mute listener is called. How do I check if the track is actually muted or not that coincides when the mute event is called?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm struggling with this as well...